# Formula for an integration on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, integration

In order to work with functions defined on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ I would like to define an adapted "integration" formula on this set. I though that following definition could be interesting:

$$  \int\limits_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} f(x) dx = \lim_{Q \to \infty} \frac{2}{(Q+1)Q}  \sum\limits_{q =1}^{Q}  \sum\limits_{a =0}^{q-1}  f(\frac{a}{q})$$

This formula has the advantage of a clear sum indexation.
But I am sure this option and other options exist in literature ? Any reference on the subject ?

With above formula it is intuitive (I think!) that for a bounded, continuous and differentiable function defined on $[0,1]$, we have:

$$  \int\limits_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} f(x) dx = \int\limits_{0}^{1}  f(x) dx$$

but it is not obvious to prove it. Any idea of a demonstration or reference with similar "sum - integral" equivalences is welcome.

(This post is linked to this post :
 [On construction of a $\mathbb{Q}$ periodic function with Fourier series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238320/on-construction-of-a-mathbbq-periodic-function-with-fourier-series), in the way that I would like to use this integration for the type of functions defined in it.)

Comment: The $x$ in the RHS of the first formula is probably a typo.

Comment: Yes,thanks, I have corrected this point, it was an unfortunate typo after a cut and paste...

Comment: If $a_1,a_2,\dots$ is any sequence uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, then $$\lim_{N\to\infty}{1\over N}\sum_1^Nf(a_n)=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$. I believe Weyl had this in the 1916 paper in which he introduced the concept of uniformly distributed sequences. Your sequence of rationals qualifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Letting $$S(q) = \dfrac{1}{q} \sum_{a=0}^{q-1} f(a/q)$$
(which is a Riemann sum for $J = \int_0^1 f(x)\; dx$) and
$$ R(Q) = \sum_{q=1}^Q \dfrac{2q}{Q(Q+1)} S(q)$$ you are defining
$$ \int_{\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]} f(x)\; dx = \lim_{Q \to \infty} R(Q)$$

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that $|S(q) - J| < \epsilon$ for $q \ge N$, and then for $Q > N$
$$ \eqalign{|R(Q) - J| &\le \sum_{q< N} \dfrac{2q}{Q(Q+1)} |S(q)-J| + \epsilon \sum_{q=N}^Q \dfrac{2q}{Q(Q+1)}\cr
&\le \dfrac{N(N+1)}{Q(Q+1)}(\|f\|_\infty + |J|)  + \epsilon } $$
which is less than $2\epsilon$ if $Q$ is sufficiently large.  Thus indeed $\lim_{Q \to \infty} R(Q) = J$.

Comment: For a function $f$ on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, the continuous extension to $[0,1]$ exists iff $f$ is uniformly continuous.